# React-Native Run-Android

Tags: android, react-native, sdk

React-native run-android not working It will build an app 99% then it will show error like this:

```
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Moto G (4) - 7.0' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 8.603 secs
Running D:\Android_SDK\Sdk\tools\bin/platform-tools/adb -s ZY2238WJXB reverse tc
p:8081 tcp:8081
Could not run adb reverse: spawnSync D:\Android_SDK\Sdk\tools\bin/platform-tools
/adb ENOENT
Starting the app on ZY2238WJXB (D:\Android_SDK\Sdk\tools\bin/platform-tools/adb
-s ZY2238WJXB shell am start -n com.localpropertys/com.localpropertys.MainActivi
ty)...
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:235:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

How can I resolve that?

environment set up  D:\Android_SDK\Sdk\tools\bin

Answer (score 0):

You're code is throwing the error not the CMD. The reason why you can't trace it is because you didn't catch the error. A function in your code isn't working and it's throwing an error.

Comment: Do you have an event handler or a listener? If so... throw a catch in them and see if you can pin point the error.